# Как поставить контейнер inline?

Tags: css

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 transition: .3s;
 background: url('img/crossword.png');
}

.header {
 margin: 10px auto;
 width: 960px;
 height: 400px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 950px){
 .header {
  width: 600px;
  background: #000;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 610px){
 .header {
  width: 200px;
  background: #000;
 }
}

.container {
 display: inline;
}

.first {
 margin: 10px auto;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

.second {
 margin: 10px auto;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header"></div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Как поставить контейнер inline

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Поставить в строку

Comment: объясни нормально, чего ты хочешь добиться? не понятна суть вопроса...

Answer (score 1):

Пропишите `display: inline-block;` элементам:

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 transition: .3s;
 background: url('img/crossword.png');
}

.header {
 margin: 10px auto;
 width: 960px;
 height: 400px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 950px){
 .header {
  width: 600px;
  background: #000;
 }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 610px){
 .header {
  width: 200px;
  background: #000;
 }
}

.container {
 display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.first {
 margin: 10px auto;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  
  display: inline-block;
}

.second {
 margin: 10px auto;
 width: 300px;
 height: 200px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header"></div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите чтоб 2 блока стояли в один ряд проще прописать: display:flex;